# How does the BindAttribute work in binding the database columns to the program?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I used an ADO.NET controller template in order to try and understand how to connect and manipulate databases through MVC. I came across this line in the Create method and I'm struggling to understand what's being bound to what.

```cs
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserID,First_Name,Surname,Password,Phone_Number,Email,IsAdmin")] UsersTable UsersTable)
```

My current understanding is that the fields of UsersTable is being bound to the method so the method can manipulate the fields. Is this correct or am I entirely wrong?

Comment: This line used for passing data for view to controller

Comment: Database manipulation can be start controller get passing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the values passed in your payload when you call the `Create` action method - typically a `POST` - will be bound to the properties of your POCO class, `UsersTable`. `Include` means that these properties will be included, and all the others will not, there is also an `Exclude` version, meaning exactly the opposite, but you can leave them all out, meaning, all values sent will be bound to properties with the same name.